# How can i list the different instances of a Azure app service and restart an instance?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have a app service in Azure that has been scaled out to 5 instances. I can list the instances via the following az cli command

```
   az webapp list-instances
```

But how can i tell which instance has frozen or is not responding and restart it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some powershell to call the REST API to fetch a list of instances, and call a health probe on each one:

```
## 1. define environment
$subscriptionId = "redacted";
$resourceGroup = "redacted";
$webAppName = "redacted";

$staging = $false

# 2. get a list of instances:

$token = Get-AzAccessToken;
$RequestHeader = @{
    Authorization  = "Bearer $($token.Token)";
    'Content-Type' = "application/json";
}
if ($staging) {
    $instancesUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/resourcegroups/$($resourceGroup)/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$($webAppName)/slots/staging/instances?api-version=2022-03-01";
} else {
    $instancesUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/resourcegroups/$($resourceGroup)/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$($webAppName)/instances?api-version=2022-03-01";
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $RequestHeader -Uri $instancesUrl | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | Select-Object -ExpandProperty properties;

# 2. do a health-check on each instance:

$instances = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $RequestHeader -Uri $instancesUrl | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | Select-Object -ExpandProperty properties;

$webAppDomain = "$($webAppName).azurewebsites.net";
$webAppUrl = "https://$($webAppDomain)/healthprobe.html";

foreach ($instance in $instances)
{
    $instanceId = $instance.Name
    "Going to check healthprobe URL on instance $($instanceId)";
    $s = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
    $c = New-Object System.Net.Cookie('ARRAffinity',$instanceId,'/',$webAppDomain)
    $s.Cookies.Add($c)
    Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Get -Uri $webAppUrl -WebSession $s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With frozen/not responding I assume you speak about a web server that is not responding to HTTP requests (if you meant something else with frozen/not responding, please clarify in your answer above).

In this case Azure App Services can handle the restart itself when you configure a **health check**.

1. Open the App Service app in the azure portal
2. Under **Monitoring**, select **Health check**.
3. Select **Enable** and provide a valid **URL path** on your application, then save

The URL you provided should return **status 200** as long as the app is responsive.

Here is the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet

UPDATE: A few comments on your questions, @Sarah:

- When you configure a health check, you provide the local **path** that Azure *"pings to check for unhealthy instances"* and a *"**time** an unhealth instance remains in the load balancer until it gets removed"* . Check the link to the documentation above
- You configure the path for the health check. So if the full URL of your health check route was `testapp.azurewebsites.net/health`, you configure `/health`
- Regarding authorization: If you implement authorization in your application code, the `/health` route should work without authentication. If you configure Authorization in the Azure Web app (e.g. in the Azure Portal again), Azure knows how to route the health check without authorization
- Checking the health of each instance from the public internet? Then you must work around the App Service load balancer - not sure how to do that...

Comment: In the scenario , where an instance is spun up to handle the work load, what if that new instance that is spun up is causing the problem and i want to restart that instance only ?

Comment: AFAK the health check works on the instance-level. So each instance will be checked regularly on the health check route. If any instance fails to respond, Azure will no longer send traffic to this specific instance and replace it with a new (expected to be healthy) instance.

Comment: Oh right and i assume Azure will try to repair that faulty instance ?

Comment: Well, Azure will shut down the frozen instance and start a new one (as Azure has no idea on how to "repair" your app)

Comment: Is there any way i can check a status or make a request to each instance and see if i get back a response of 200 OK maybe ?

Comment: In regards to the path under Health check , so if my app was called testapp , would the relative path be 

/testapp.azurewebsites.net     ?

Comment: Also can the health check route be configured ?

Comment: Another qn pls , do we need to authorized at all since the app requires authorization , or is health check totally independent of the app ?

Comment: I added some bullet points above. Hope that answers your questions.