# Does the Powershell cmd "Get-AzWebAppInstanceHealth" still exist?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to use the cmdlet Get-AzWebAppInstanceHealth in powershell , but it gives an error :

```
 Get-AzWebAppInstanceHealth : The term 'Get-AzWebAppInstanceHealth' is not recognized as 
 the name of a cmdlet
```

Do i need to install a certain module  ?

Comment: We don't have see any cmdlet related to health check under Az.Websites PoweShell Module or in Az WebApps CLI cmdlets. Refer to these documentations for reference [Az.Websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/?view=azps-10.3.0#app-service) PowerShell cmdlets and [Az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest) webapp Cmdlets.

Comment: Ok then how can i get health check status ?

Comment: I understand that you want to monitor the health check status of azure app service. After providing your application's Health check path, you can monitor the health of your site using Azure Monitor. From the Health check blade in the Portal, select the Metrics in the top toolbar.  Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet#monitoring) for more information.

Comment: Did you try using `az webapp list-instances` to list out it. @Traci

Comment: yes i did , but i need the isnatcne url so i can make an api request using that instance ?

Comment: Instance Uri;s will not be shown in output due to security reasons. You can only be able to view these [details](https://i.imgur.com/hGHnEWO.png). @Traci

Comment: Can you check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75815875/19785512) works in your case. @Traci

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no `PowerShell` command like `GetAzWebAppInstanceHealth` to get the instance health check details for an App service.

*To acquire instance details, use the `AzCLI` command shown below.*

```bash
 $instances=az webapp list-instances --name newappj --resource-group <resourceGroup>
 $status=$instances | convertFrom-Json
 $status.state
```

*Output:*

[image]

*References:*

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77095154/19785512) worked by me for more relevant information.

You can also refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75815875/19785512) by @Vince Bowdren to check the different list of instances with their current status and also can restart it by calling a `RESTAPI` using PowerShell.